# What points of affine space can be mapped to zero by an étale morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $n$ a positive integer.

For what points $x\in\mathbb{A}^n_K$ can I find an étale morphism $f_x:\mathbb{A}^n_K\to \mathbb{A}^n_K$ mapping $x$ to zero and how does such a morphism look like on the level of $K$-algebras $g_x:K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\to K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$?

Edit: By ''points'' $x\in\mathbb{A}^n_K$ I mean ''elements of $\operatorname{Spec} K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$'', all prime ideals.

Comment: This  is a very interesting question !

Comment: All rational points have the required property. If $n=1$ and $K$ has characteristic zero, then the converse is true because an étale morphism from $\mathbb A^1$ to $\mathbb A^1$ then has to be an automorphism. In higher dimension and characteristic zero, the same will be true if the Jacobian conjecture is true because étale implies automorphic. In positive characteristic $p$, the map $x\mapsto x^p-x$ is étale and maps non-necessarily rational point to rational point. But not all separable points in can be mapped to a rational point in general. So as said Georges, interesting but hard question

Answer (score 3):

A necessary condition for $f_x:\mathbb{A}^n_K\to \mathbb{A}^n_K$ to be étale at $x$ is that the extension $K\to \kappa(x)$ be finite separable .
This implies that $x$ is a closed point of $\mathbb{A}^n_K$, but not necessarily a rational one.

For example the morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb Q\to \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb Q$ induced by $\mathbb Q[T]\to \mathbb Q[X]: T\mapsto X^2-2$ maps the non-rational point $x\in \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb Q$ corresponding to the prime ideal $(X^2-2)\in \mathbb Q[X]$ to the origin   $0\in \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb Q$ [corresponding to $(T)\in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q[T])$] of the codomain of $f$.
This morphism $f$ is étale at $x$, but not globally étale since it is not étale at the origin $(X)\in \operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb Q[X])=\mathbb A^1_\mathbb Q$ of the  domain of the morphism $f$.

I think the search for globally étale  morphisms as in your question might be quite difficult, since even automorphisms of affine space are intractable, as witnessed by the notorious Jacobian conjecture.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, thank you for your answer. Does ''rational point'' mean ''$K$-point''? Please let me ask you a probably stupid follow-up question: Does an étale morphism map closed points (those points corresponding to maximal ideals) to closed points? If I've understood it correctly, it always true that a morphism sends $K$-points to $K$-points. Thank you.